# Firestore with Persistence Enabled returns back Document IDS that do not exist

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, persistence

I enabled Persistence on my Firebase project for Firestore.

I am getting the documents of a user via a simple call.

```
this.afs
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection("events").snapshotChanges().subscribe(...etc etc...)
```

The above call is fed to an Angular table DataSource

Perhaps the above do not matter so much but just making sure.

To the point.

The list I am getting back for the collection `events` contains items that are possibly deleted when the Firestore Persistence is enabled.

I crosschecked the IDS that persistence gives and some do not exist in the online DB.

I am not sure why/how this has happened but I am a bit confused in regards to:

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Should I be making some different call?
- Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach a listener to `snapshotChanges()` it immediately queries the local cache, and satisfies the query from that. It then connects to the server, to check for any updates. If there are any updates, it will fire `snapshotChanges()` again with the updated snapshot (and update the local cache from that).

So it is indeed possible that you get stale data in the first callback for `snapshotChanges()`.

But usually you'll just update your UI from `snapshotChanges()`, and so you'd again update the UI once the second (up to date) data comes in.

Comment: I do subscribe to the snapshot changes Frannk. I just did not include that part on my code. I am feeling that on some local delete the whole list is not updated on other devices. It's a very strange issue I am experiencing.

Comment: I deleted the indexedDB manually and problem is not reproducable strangly and now it's even more hard to debug :-(